# same dimensions pictures but displayed different !!! Why?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I had to set 4 pages with 100% width and height background depending of the screen size.
The imgs have got the same width and height and these are my settings,

```
.fullImg{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
max-height: 100vh;
max-width: 100vw;
```

}

this is working perfectly for few pictures but not with others, how is that possible if the pictures got the same dimensions?
I tried to do background-size: cover which is working for a while but then it will cut off the img so the best way so far is that one i wrote above.
I am talking about big screen sizes from 1440px to 2560px.
Thanks a lot

You can have a look at the headers here: http://provaresponsive.herokuapp.com/pr.html

Comment: how can i do? sorry I am new here

Comment: That's technically not possible, so there is a fault somewhere that we are not able to see given the limited information. My advice would be to use CSS background-image properties instead. You can see a great tutorial on it here https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: i saw this tutorial and is really nice but when i resize from 2560 to 1440 for example the image is cut, that's why i didn't use it.
how can i do jsfiddle?

Comment: If you want an image to always use all available height and width, then you have to decide: Do you want the image to retain it's aspect ratio - then it has to be cropped, or do you want the image to change aspect ratio, in which case it will stretch. Which one makes sense for you?
BTW, jsfiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/ - you will need an account in order to share your fiddles.

Comment: ok makes much more sense now but just in case can you explain me how to do both please,  which is the best way to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use backstretch js .it can fix your issue.if you call your background image using backstretch js then it will automatically adjust your image according to your screen ,whatever your image resolution is

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped

Comment: actually, it really worked but I still have an issue.
The first background has to adapt the screen and is all perfect untill now but of course I have other divs and contents below it that will overflow the firstBackground that backstretch sets as position: absolute!! How can I fix this?

Comment: can you please show me the HTML code that you wrote?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments if you want an image to always use all available height and width, then you have to decide: Do you want the image to retain it's aspect ratio - then it has to be cropped, or do you want the image to change aspect ratio, in which case it will stretch.

Here is an example for each option:

**No Stretching - Will Crop**

```
html { 
  background: url(http://www.olejarz.com/arted/perspective/images/intro.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asimovwasright/2h8nxh2q/1/)

**Stretching - No Cropping**

```
div { 
 background-image:url(http://www.olejarz.com/arted/perspective/images/intro.gif);
 /* 
  * Width & Height can be percetages only when the parent 
  * element has explicitly declared dimensions.
  */
  height:200px; 
  width:500px;
  -moz-background-size:100% 100%;
  -webkit-background-size:100% 100%;
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asimovwasright/bac8ft6m/1/)

And there is a third option, you probably won't like, which is to contain the image, so:

**No Stretching, No Cropping - not filling the x/y**

```
html { 
  background: url(http://www.olejarz.com/arted/perspective/images/intro.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  -o-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asimovwasright/e1y7naxu/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped